# How was the ACT party's 2005 proposal to repeal the nuclear propulsion ban in New Zealand defeated?

Tags: parliament, legislation, nuclear-energy, new-zealand

I was able to find a proposal [from 2005](https://www.scoop.co.nz/stories/PA0506/S00185.htm) of the ACT party that would have repealed the nuclear propulsion ban in New Zealand's waters. I'm fairly sure this proposal/repeal was defeated, but how did that happen exactly? Did it die in a committee? Was it put to a floor vote?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *How was the ACT party's 2005 proposal to repeal the nuclear propulsion ban in New Zealand defeated?*

Motion not agreed to.

---

The debate is in [New Zealand Nuclear Free Zone, Disarmament, and Arms Control (Nuclear Propulsion Reform) Amendment Bill — First Reading](https://www.parliament.nz/en/pb/hansard-debates/rhr/document/47HansD_20050727_00001577/new-zealand-nuclear-free-zone-disarmament-and-arms-control).

> **Hon KEN SHIRLEY (ACT):** [...] My bill is very simple. It merely proposes the removal of section 11. I would like to draw to the House’s attention Supplementary Order Paper 386, which lies on the Table. It states that my bill would not become operative until we had had a referendum of the New Zealand voting public. How can members vote against that? This is an important issue. Various political parties have somewhat entrenched views on it. This Supplementary Order Paper is saying that this bill would not become operative until a majority of New Zealand citizens said that, yes, we should lift this ban. How can members oppose that? Will Labour say, because of its blind, cold war mantra, that it will deny the New Zealand public the right to have that referendum?

The vote was:

> - Ayes 9  ACT New Zealand 9.
> - Noes 107    New Zealand Labour 51; New Zealand National 26; New Zealand First 13; Green Party 9; United Future 7; Māori Party 1.